# Log a TCP stream so it can be opened in Wireshark

Tags: logging, tcp, wireshark

I have an application that opens a TCP socket and sends and receives some data binary data. I would like the application to be able to log the sent and recieved data into a format that can be opened with Wireshark and dissected as a TCP stream using the normal built-in and custom dissectors.

I considered directly writing pcap or pcapng files, but it looks like they require full TCP and IP headers, even when using DLT_RAW. I only have easy access to the TCP payload, not details of the actual TCP or IP packets.

It looks like Wireshark supports opening several other file formats. Is there a file format that would be reasonably easy to write to that could handle TCP streams rather than individual packets?

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you're saying you don't have access to the TCP headers, just the application data stream. So you don't have an actual TCP stream for Wireshark to analyze, just an application data stream. Does Wireshark have dissectors for the kind of application data you're dealing with?

Comment: Yes, it does. Some of what we handle is HTTP, and some is a custom protocol that we wrote plugins for Wireshark to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually find an answer: I can write out a pcap file using the `LINKTYPE_WIRESHARK_UPPER_PDU` encapsulation (integer value 252, sort-of documented [here](https://pcapng.github.io/pcapng/draft-gharris-opsawg-pcap.html#name-linktype-registry) but mostly documented in the [Wireshark source code](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-pcap_pktdata.c#L217)).

I can even store the source and destination IPs and ports using [protocol-specific optional data](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/exported_pdu.h#L97-104).

This will be loaded as TCP data, but without any of the encapsulating packet data.